# Do I need to say "I give you divorce" to divorce my wife?

Tags: hadith, sunni, women, sunnah

If the wife says give me divorce in anger and the husband says, go you are divorced instead of saying that i give you divorce, is that then a valid divorce?

What are the accurate words to pronounce when divorcing the wife? Does divorce only occur when husband say, "i give you divorce" or when he says, "go you are given divorce"?

Comment: I don't think this is a multilingual site as most questions are asked and answered in English. Care to translate?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A marriage is broken the same way, it was made. If you have to divorce your wife, you must undergo a proper procedure. Just saying it Divorce three times, on your wife face does not fulfill the criteria of divorce.

It is made official in the presence of witnesses and a Preacher(Mullah) will confirm the will of both to embrace the divorce.

After a divorce is done, a woman must undergo, a period of 3 months and 10 days, to find out if she if she is pregnant to his divorced husband or not. After the completion of this duration, a woman can marry any person, but the person she just divorced.

1. [Reference 1:](https://www.ma-law.org.pk/Divorce_in_islam_what_is_Divorce_how_to_divorce_about_divorce_when_to_divorce.html)
2. [Reference 2:](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/235027551-divorce/)

Comment: I am so confused .. i know that there is a proper procedure but is it necessary that the word "i" should be said like " i give you divorce"  ... if go you are given divorce is said is the divorce is still valid?... ( agar kaha jae k ja di tujhy talak to kia talak ho jati hai ? Ya kehna zarori hai k mae tmhy talak daita hn ?

Comment: No, just saying it does not apply divorce.

Comment: It does actually.

Comment: This answer is just plain false. Saying to your wife you divorce her on three separate occasions, while haram, has the legal effect of breaking the marriage according to most scholars I'm aware of.

Comment: Not all sects consider it the exact same. For a complete divorce, it is important to have witnesses and official stamp paper to confirm the divorce in the presence of Mullah(priest ).

Comment: I have added the references @Bach. You can confirm it there.

Comment: You're talking about Pakistani law, not sharia.

Answer (score 0):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

**There are no specific sequence of words to repeat for a talaaq to be valid, it just had to be the intention(by any reason) and the words should mean that person is giving divorce.** So it can be anything like, i give you divorce, you are divorced, i divorce you or anything.

**And these words can be in front of wife or even in her absence, can be verbal or can be written**, if the intention was to actually divorce(even if in anger) and it was said or written, divorce is valid.

But, if the intention was there and words were not spoken or written, i.e he did not expressed it. Than divorce is not valid because:

> Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said: The Messenger
>   of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: **“Allaah
>   has forgiven my ummah for whatever crosses their minds, so long as
>   they do not act upon it or speak of it.”** Qutaadah – one of the
>   narrators of this hadeeth – said: If it said the words of divorce to
>   himself, without uttering it, it does not mean anything.

PS: If this was said once, the divorce is valid but only 1, and the couple can be together again without a re-marriage(nikah) with-in iddah and with a re-marriage after iddah. And if it was said thrice, than it depends because some schools of thoughts consider it one valid divorce(not 3, if 3 divorce was given in same sitting) and some(specially hanafi) schools of thought consider it 3 valid divorces. So, it depends

### Allah knows best